# Keeping edge values in graph after converting it to a network object in R

Tags: r, graph, social-networking, adjacency-matrix, sna

Note 1: I'm using the R packages "network" and "sna"

Note 2: My original data are in edgelist format in a .csv file.

I've been looking for the best way to read in edgelist data into R. At first sight, this is simple.

```
data <- read.csv("file.CSV", header=F)
network <- network(data, matrix.type="edgelist", directed=F) #convert data to network object
val<-data[,3] #here are the values for my edges
set.edge.value(network, "val", val, e=1:length(network$mel))
```

When I ask the network to return edge values (get.edge.values), it returns the correct values.

However, when I ask `summary(network)`, it just returns an adjacency matrix where all values are set to 1 (with exception of the diagonal). Even if they had the value of zero, they get a value of 1.

Moreover, trying to get something like degree(network) returns wrong results.

I have been searching for days on this. A possible solution was to use `network2<-as.matrix.network(netwerk1, matrix.type="adjacency", attrname="val")`. This works. The problem, however, is that this ceases to be a network object and becomes a matrix class. As a result, I cannot add vertex attributes to the network.  Converting network2 back to a network object again looses the edge values in the network.

Some help would really be appreciated.

Best,
Frederik

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you answered your own question: when converting a network object to a matrix, you need to include the `attrname` argument to tell `as.matrix.network` which attribute to use for the weights. Can you explain why you need to convert it back to a network object if it already is one?

The `degree` function in the `sna` does not have an argument to tell it which edge attribute to use, so you have to pass it a matrix that has the weights.

```
> library(network)
> library(sna)
> net<-network.initialize(3)
> add.edges(net,c(1,2,3),c(2,3,1))
> set.edge.attribute(net,'weight',c(5,6,7))
> as.matrix(net,matrix.type='adjacency',attrname='weight')
  1 2 3
1 0 5 0
2 0 0 6
3 7 0 0
> netmat<-as.matrix(net,matrix.type='adjacency',attrname='weight')
> degree(net)
[1] 2 2 2
> degree(netmat)
[1] 12 11 13
```

So in your case,

```
degree(network2)
```

should work.

Comment: Well, the reason for wanting a network object is so I can run network related functions on it. Using as.matrix.network does not yield a network object. However, I did find a solution using the igraph package.